# Importing CSV lines into a class

Tags: python, csv, object, import

This is an offensively simple question and I feel bad for even asking it, so some extent. I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for two days now.

I'm trying do to an object oriented program that takes the lines of a csv and turns each line of that CSV into a variable that I can use down the road. I want to somehow (I can't figure out how) get each line of that CSV into a class. I know this might not even be the best way to do this but I'm constrained to solve the problem in this way for other reasons.

I don't know enough Python to even know how to look up a solution to this and I need to know how to do this for a project I'm working on.

Here is the code I am basing this off:

```
import argparse
from collections import defaultdict
import csv


class Actor(object):
    """An actor with bounded rationality.

    The methods on this class such as u_success, u_failure, eu_challenge are
    meant to be calculated from the actor's perspective, which in practice
    means that the actor's risk aversion is always used, including to calculate
    utilities for other actors.

    I don't understand why an actor would assume that other actors share the
    same risk aversion, or how this implies that it is from the given actor's
    point of view, but as far as I can tell this is faithful to BDM's original
    formulation as well as Scholz's replication.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, c, s, x, model, r=1.0):
        self.name = name
        self.c = c  # capabilities, float between 0 and 1
        self.s = s  # salience, float between 0 and 1
        self.x = x  # number representing position on an issue
        self.model = model
        self.r = r  # risk aversion, float between .5 and 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(x=%s,c=%s,s=%s,r=%.2f)' % (
            self.name, self.x, self.c, self.s, self.r)

    def compare(self, x_j, x_k, risk=None):
        """Difference in utility to `self` between positions x_j and x_k."""
        risk = risk or self.r

        position_range = self.model.position_range
        x_k_distance = (abs(self.x - x_k) / position_range) ** risk
        x_j_distance = (abs(self.x - x_j) / position_range) ** risk
        return self.c * self.s * (x_k_distance - x_j_distance)

    def u_success(self, actor, x_j):
        """Utility to `actor` successfully challenging position x_j."""
        position_range = self.model.position_range
        val = 0.5 - 0.5 * abs(actor.x - x_j) / position_range
        return 2 - 4 * val ** self.r

    def u_failure(self, actor, x_j):
        """Utility to `actor` of failing in challenge position x_j."""
        position_range = self.model.position_range
        val = 0.5 + 0.5 * abs(actor.x - x_j) / position_range
        return 2 - 4 * val ** self.r

    def u_status_quo(self):
        """Utility to `self` of the status quo."""
        return 2 - 4 * (0.5 ** self.r)

    def eu_challenge(self, actor_i, actor_j):
        """Expected utility to `actor_i' of `actor_i` challenging `actor_j`.

        This is calculated from the perspective of actor `self`, which in
        practice means that `self.r` is used for risk aversion.
        """
        prob_success = self.model.probability(actor_i.x, actor_j.x)
        u_success = self.u_success(actor_i, actor_j.x)
        u_failure = self.u_failure(actor_i, actor_j.x)
        u_status_quo = self.u_status_quo()

        eu_resist = actor_j.s * (
            prob_success * u_success + (1 - prob_success) * u_failure)
        eu_not_resist = (1 - actor_j.s) * u_success
        eu_status_quo = self.model.q * u_status_quo

        return eu_resist + eu_not_resist - eu_status_quo

    def danger_level(self):
        """The amount of danger the actor is in from holding its policy position.

        The smaller this number is, the more secure the actor is, in that it
        expects fewer challenges to its position from other actors.
        """
        return sum(self.eu_challenge(other_actor, self) for other_actor
                   in self.model.actors if other_actor != self)

    def risk_acceptance(self):
        """Actor's risk acceptance, based on its current policy position.

        I have two comments:
        - It seems to me that BDM's intent was that in order to calculate
          risk acceptance, one would need to compare an actor's danger level
          across different policy positions that the actor could hold. Instead,
          Scholz compares the actor's danger level to the danger level of all
          other actors. This comparison doesn't seem relevant, given that other
          actors will have danger levels not possible for the given actor
          because of differences in salience and capability.
        - Even (what I assume to be) BDM's original intention is an odd way to
          calculate risk acceptance, given that the actor's policy position may
          have been coerced, rather than having been chosen by the actor based
          on its security preferences.
        """

        # Alternative calculation, which I think is more faithful to
        # BDM's original intent.

        # orig_position = self.x
        # possible_dangers = []
        # for position in self.model.positions():
        #     self.x = position
        #     possible_dangers.append(self.danger_level())
        # self.x = orig_position

        # max_danger = max(possible_dangers)
        # min_danger = min(possible_dangers)

        # return ((2 * self.danger_level() - max_danger - min_danger) /
        #         (max_danger - min_danger))

        danger_levels = [actor.danger_level() for actor in self.model.actors]
        max_danger = max(danger_levels)
        min_danger = min(danger_levels)
        return ((2 * self.danger_level() - max_danger - min_danger) /
                (max_danger - min_danger))

    def risk_aversion(self):
        risk = self.risk_acceptance()
        return (1 - risk / 3.0) / (1 + risk / 3.0)

    def best_offer(self):
        offers = defaultdict(list)

        for other_actor in self.model.actors:
            if self.x == other_actor.x:
                continue

            offer = Offer.from_actors(self, other_actor)
            if offer:
                offers[offer.offer_type].append(offer)

        best_offer = None
        best_offer_key = lambda offer: abs(self.x - offer.position)

        # This is faithful to Scholz' original code, but it appears to be a
        # mistake, since Scholz' paper and BDM clearly state that each actor
        # chooses the offer that requires him to change position the
        # least. Instead, Scholz included a special case for compromises which
        # results in some bizarre behavior, particularly in Round 4 when
        # Belgium compromises with Netherlands to an extreme position rather
        # than with France.
        def compromise_best_offer_key(offer):
            top = (abs(offer.eu) * offer.actor.x +
                   abs(offer.other_eu) * offer.other_actor.x)
            return top / (abs(offer.eu) + abs(offer.other_eu))

        if offers['confrontation']:
            best_offer = min(offers['confrontation'], key=best_offer_key)
        elif offers['compromise']:
            best_offer = min(offers['compromise'],
                             key=compromise_best_offer_key)
        elif offers['capitulation']:
            best_offer = min(offers['capitulation'], key=best_offer_key)

        return best_offer


class Offer(object):
    CONFRONTATION = 'confrontation'
    COMPROMISE = 'compromise'
    CAPITULATION = 'capitulation'
    OFFER_TYPES = (
        CONFRONTATION,
        COMPROMISE,
        CAPITULATION,
    )

    def __init__(self, actor, other_actor, offer_type, eu, other_eu, position):
        if offer_type not in self.OFFER_TYPES:
            raise ValueError('offer_type "%s" not in %s'
                             % (offer_type, self.OFFER_TYPES))

        self.actor = actor  # actor receiving the offer
        self.other_actor = other_actor  # actor proposing the offer
        self.offer_type = offer_type
        self.eu = eu
        self.other_eu = other_eu
        self.position = position

    @classmethod
    def from_actors(cls, actor, other_actor):
        eu_ij = actor.eu_challenge(actor, other_actor)
        eu_ji = actor.eu_challenge(other_actor, actor)

        if eu_ji > eu_ij > 0:
            offer_type = cls.CONFRONTATION
            position = other_actor.x
        elif eu_ji > 0 > eu_ij and eu_ji > abs(eu_ij):
            offer_type = cls.COMPROMISE
            concession = (other_actor.x - actor.x) * abs(eu_ij / eu_ji)
            position = actor.x + concession
        elif eu_ji > 0 > eu_ij and eu_ji < abs(eu_ji):
            offer_type = cls.CAPITULATION
            position = other_actor.x
        else:
            return None

        return cls(actor, other_actor, offer_type, eu_ij, eu_ji, position)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        type_to_fmt = {
            self.CONFRONTATION: '%s loses confrontation to %s',
            self.COMPROMISE: '%s compromises with %s',
            self.CAPITULATION: '%s capitulates to %s',
        }
        fmt = type_to_fmt[self.offer_type] + "\n\t%s vs %s\n\tnew_pos = %s"

        return fmt % (self.actor.name, self.other_actor.name, self.eu,
                      self.other_eu, self.position)


class BDMScholzModel(object):
    """An expected utility model for political forecasting."""

    def __init__(self, data, q=1.0):
        self.actors = [
            Actor(name=item['Actor'],
                  c=float(item['Capability']),
                  s=float(item['Salience']),
                  x=float(item['Position']),
                  model=self)
            for item in data]
        self.name_to_actor = {actor.name: actor for actor in self.actors}
        self.q = q
        positions = self.positions()
        self.position_range = max(positions) - min(positions)

    @classmethod
    def from_csv_path(cls, csv_path):
        return cls(csv.DictReader(open(csv_path, 'rU')))

    def actor_by_name(self, name):
        return self.name_to_actor.get(name)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.name_to_actor.get(key)

    def positions(self):
        return list({actor.x for actor in self.actors})

    def median_position(self):
        positions = self.positions()
        median = positions[0]
        for position in positions[1:]:
            votes = sum(actor.compare(position, median, risk=1.0)
                        for actor in self.actors)
            if votes > 0:
                median = position
        return median

    def mean_position(self):
        return (sum(actor.c * actor.s * actor.x for actor in self.actors) /
                sum(actor.c * actor.s for actor in self.actors))

    def probability(self, x_i, x_j):
        if x_i == x_j:
            return 0.0

        # `sum_all_votes` below is faithful to Scholz' code, but I think it is
        # quite contrary to BDM's intent. Instead, we should have.
        # denominator = sum(actor.compare(x_i, x_j) for actor in self.actors)

        # This would make sure that prob(x_i, x_j) + prob(x_j, x_i) == 1.
        # However, because of the odd way that salience values are used as
        # the probability that an actor will resist a proposal, this results in
        # the actors almost always confronting each other.

        # My theory is that Scholz got around the confrontation problem by
        # introducing this large denominator, causing extremely small
        # probability values. This prevents actors from confronting each other
        # constantly, but the result is comical, in that the challenging actor
        # always has a vanishingly small chance of winning a conflict, yet the
        # challenged actor often gives up without a fight because of low
        # salience.
        sum_all_votes = sum(abs(actor.compare(a1.x, a2.x))
                            for actor in self.actors
                            for a1 in self.actors
                            for a2 in self.actors)
        return (sum(max(0, actor.compare(x_i, x_j)) for actor in self.actors) /
                sum_all_votes)

    def update_risk_aversions(self):
        for actor in self.actors:
            actor.r = 1.0

        actor_to_risk_aversion = [(actor, actor.risk_aversion())
                                  for actor in self.actors]
        for actor, risk_aversion in actor_to_risk_aversion:
            actor.r = risk_aversion

    def update_positions(self):
        actor_to_best_offer = [(actor, actor.best_offer())
                               for actor in self.actors]
        for actor, best_offer in actor_to_best_offer:
            if best_offer:
                print best_offer
                actor.x = best_offer.position

    def run_model(self, num_rounds=1):
        print 'Median position: %s' % self.median_position()
        print 'Mean position: %s' % self.mean_position()

        for round_ in range(1, num_rounds + 1):
            print ''
            print 'ROUND %d' % round_
            self.update_risk_aversions()
            self.update_positions()

            print ''
            print 'Median position: %s' % self.median_position()
            print 'Mean position: %s' % self.mean_position()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'csv_path',
        help='path to csv with input data')
    parser.add_argument(
        'num_rounds',
        help='number of rounds of simulation to run',
        type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    model = BDMScholzModel.from_csv_path(args.csv_path)
    model.run_model(num_rounds=args.num_rounds)
```

Comment: Please provide us with specific code snippets from this larger file that needs our attention. I can't find what you're referring to.

Comment: You should describe your actual problem and not dump (too large) code that isn't actually attempting to solve your problem.   This code does load each line of a CSV into a class that is stored in a container class and is rather straightforward.  Get a source debugger and step line-by-line through the code, looking up any functions you don't understand.  Use that knowledge to attempt to solve your problem.  If anything is unclear, ask a specific question about *that*.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want to read a CSV file and return a list of objects, one for each row of your file. Your `BDMScholzModel.from_csv_path()` function already does this (although it's probably better to use `with` to manage the context of the file input instead of simply opening it, but that's beside the point). You have a list of `Actor` objects in the `actors` attribute of your `BDMScholzModel` object. What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Please provide a [mre] that contains only that code relevant to your _specific_ problem.

Comment: To Hosangadi, thank you I understand now a little better what code I should be looking at. I am basically at a loss to try to reverse engineer this thing and I'll dissect that and the @classmethod section more. I'm essentially at this point where I wasn't really aware of even how to dissect this code because, I should have mentioned this earlier, it's not mine.

Comment: I'm basically going to consider this matter closed because I know more what I need to look up. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hey, have you made any progress? I read your code and can see what you missed. Check out my break-down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a lot of code, but reading the code, and then running it, I can see what's going on.

You're probably getting this error:

```
% python2 so.py sample.csv 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 336, in <module>
    model = BDMScholzModel.from_csv_path(args.csv_path)
  File "so.py", line 241, in from_csv_path
    return cls(csv.DictReader(open(csv_path, 'rU')))
  File "so.py", line 233, in __init__
    for item in data]
KeyError: 'Actor'
```

And you're getting that error because just creating a **DictReader** doesn't actually read the data, that's still a set of steps you have to explicitly carry out.  Here's the minimal example from the Python2 docs for [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.DictReader):

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

In your case, you want to pass a list of dicts to your BDMScholzModel constructor, and in its `__init__()` method turn those individual dicts into Actors.

So, your `from_csv_path()` classmethod needs to look more like that example, with these changes:

- create an empty list before creating the reader, `data = []`
- inside the row-in-reader loop, just append each row to data, `data.append(row)` (DictReader handles the field/key names for you)
- after the whole with-open block, finally call your BDMScholzModel initializer w/your data, `return cls(data)`

I did all that.  Then sketched up this sample CSV:

**sample.csv**

```
Actor,Capability,Salience,Position
foo,1,1,1
bar,2,2,2
baz,3,3,3
```

I also added a debug-print statement just before the `cls(data)` call at the end of my new `from_csv_path()` classmethod:

```
print 'debug data: %s\n' % data
return cls(data)
```

And running:

```sh
python2 so.py sample.csv 1
```

got me:

```
debug data: [
  {'Capability': '1', 'Position': '1', 'Salience': '1', 'Actor': 'foo'}, 
  {'Capability': '2', 'Position': '2', 'Salience': '2', 'Actor': 'bar'}, 
  {'Capability': '3', 'Position': '3', 'Salience': '3', 'Actor': 'baz'}
]

Median position: 3.0
Mean position: 2.57142857143

ROUND 1

Median position: 3.0
Mean position: 2.57142857143
```

Here's my complete `from_csv_path()` method:

```
@classmethod
def from_csv_path(cls, csv_path):
    data = []
    with open(csv_path) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
    print 'debug data: %s\n' % data
    return cls(data)
```

Comment: Since you seem to have already done the work, can you email me the full script? Honestly I'm switching from doing basic data analysis with R to doing object oriented stuff with Python and I honestly just feel like I got a brick wall dumped on me. I have very little idea what I'm doing with Python and I'll basically take all of the notes I can, even the most trivial. Your response is amazing, by the way.

Comment: @rulesforpower, here's [the updated script](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/e33cc0bbf86823313f37cfdde441af6a#file-program-py). And here's [the diff](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/e33cc0bbf86823313f37cfdde441af6a/revisions) with my changes on top. Also, please check this answer off as accepted, if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Can do, thank you so much!